# datatables dont reload ajax

Tags: javascript, datatables

I need to reload data periodically from an api endpoint on datatables. for that I wrote such code:

```
        "ajax": {
          url: "/report",
          data: function(){
            dataSrc = "data";
          }
        },

        "columns": [
            {data: "garson_id"},
            {data: "siparis_alan"},
            {data: "siparis_grup"},
            {data: "siparis_masano"},
            {data: "kisi_sayisi"},
            {data: "odeme_yontemi"},
            {data: "masa_fiyat"},
            {data: "zaman_pulu"}
        ],


setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 3000 );
```

It gives me only one load and doesnt get new data from url.

Comment: Any errors or messages shown on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I put setinterval function inside datatable function it worked.